# Image not showing in angularjs, mobile

Tags: angularjs, blackberry-webworks, indexeddb

Image not showing in ng-repeat, getting all data from indexeddb and binding to page everything show up expect img in blackberry 10 webworks

```
<img data-ng-src='{{item.Picture}}' width="100px;" height="100px;"/>

   {
    id:48758,
    Botanical_name:"Cladothamnus pyroliflorus",
    Common_name:"Himalayan Cotoneaster ",
    Picture: "images/Fplants/Cladothamnus pyroliflorus.png",
    },...
```

Comment: Try adding a slash(/) before the url and remove space from file name.

Comment: I don't think this is an issue with the indexeddb but rather with the url to the image not being correct.

Comment: @user1024610 if you still suspect IDB after checking out my answer, please provide your IDB code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
app.config(['$routeProvider','$compileProvider',function($routeProvider, $compileProvider){        $compileProvider.imgSrcSanitizationWhitelist('img/');
```

Answer (score 0):

This wouldn't seem like an issue with IndexedDB.

For non-Angular directive attributes, such as `src` you want to interpolate as in the code below:

```
<img src='{{item.Picture}}' width="100px;" height="100px;"/>
```

For Angular directive attributes, there's no need for such interpolation:

```
<img data-ng-src='item.Picture' width="100px;" height="100px;"/>
```

As your data is going to be `undefined` on bootstrap, you want to use the latter approach. It prevents the browser from trying to load `undefined` as an image source.

Also, please note vaibhav's comment above. Without a leading slash, you'll load the `images` directory as relative to the current. While that may be what you're going for, it's probably going to make your code more reusable to include the leading slash regardless.

**Update**: If you're in an `ng-repeat`, note that your scope is not the scope in which the `ng-repeat` directive appears but it's own, brand new scope. Perhaps try out `$parent.item.Picture`

Comment: i try all above and more and still not working, <img data-ng-src='{{item.Picture}}' width="100px;" height="100px;"/>
      <img data-ng-src="/images/Fplants/{{item.Botanical_name}}.png" width="200px;" height="200px;">
      <img data-ng-src="images/Fplants/{{item.Botanical_name}}.png" width="200px;" height="200px;">
      <img data-ng-src='item.Picture' width="100px;" height="100px;"/>, my folder structure, www>images>Fplants

Comment: and other think when i run in browser images show up

Comment: if i used <img ng:src="http://angularjs.org/img/AngularJS-large.png"/> it show up

Comment: Sounds like a scope issue. I didn't notice you were in an `ng-repeat`. Updated answer, but my earlier note on interpolation should still apply.

Comment: i have ng-repeat, i just test with image base64 string and its working as that

Comment: Both base64 and your `http://angularjs.org/img/AngularJS-large.png` example both don't rely on any `$scope` so that makes sense. Did you try reaching into the `$parent` scope?

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem, it occurs with the image filename having spaces in between , maybe we could write a directive the removes the space from the filename as I'm calling the image via other variable such as title..